# Automate running .exe program using Command line scripts in win10

Tags: windows

I'm using Windows 10. I have program with GUI interface that I have to fill each space with numbers and names. Then click run to upload the information to the memory of my device. This is a repeated task. I need to automate it using special script in command using a file called DefaultCIS.ini ( editable file located in the program directory). Moreover, I need to press click to upload the new information into the memory of the external device.

I have used this commands in the CMD to run the program with the edited DefaultCIS.ini file at once.

C:\Program Files (x86)\ProgramName> ProgramName.exe DefaultCIS.ini

I need to automate the previous command with clicking the buttons located in the GUI of the program.